# How does the typecheck macro from the Linux kernel work?

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel

The file `include/linux/typecheck.h` of the Linux kernel 4.16 contains this code.

```
#define typecheck(type,x) \
({      type __dummy; \
        typeof(x) __dummy2; \
        (void)(&__dummy == &__dummy2); \
        1; \
}
```

which checks if `x` is the same type as the parameter `type`.

But I can't understand the line:

```
 (void)(&__dummy == &__dummy2);
```

How does comparing the first address of both variables help?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Comparing pointers with incompatible types is a constraint violation and requires the compiler to issue a diagnostic. See 6.5.9 Equality operators:

> Constraints
>
> One of the following shall hold:
>
> - both operands have arithmetic type;
> - both operands are pointers to qualified or unqualified versions of compatible types;
> - one operand is a pointer to an object or incomplete type and the other is a pointer to a qualified or unqualified version of void; or
> - one operand is a pointer and the other is a null pointer constant.

and 5.1.1.3 Diagnostics:

> A conforming implementation shall produce at least one diagnostic message (identified in an implementation-defined manner) if a preprocessing translation unit or translation unit contains a violation of any syntax rule or constraint, even if the behavior is also explicitly specified as undefined or implementation-defined. Diagnostic messages need not be produced in other circumstances.

Answer (score 12):

This uses two GCC extensions — expression statements `({ ... })` and `typeof()`.

1. The first line of the expansion declares a variable of the named type `type`.
2. The second line of the expansion declares a variable of the same type as the variable or expression `x`.
3. The third line compares the two pointers, which will only match if the types of the two dummy variables match, generating a pointer mismatch warning (or error if compiling with `-Werror`).
4. The last line (containing the `1`) is the value of the expression — equivalent to true.

So, you get a compilation warning/error if the type of `x` is not the same as the named type.

Example code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define typecheck(type,x) \
({      type __dummy; \
        typeof(x) __dummy2; \
        (void)(&__dummy == &__dummy2); \
        1; \
})

int main(void)
{
    int x;
    if (typecheck(int, x))
        printf("int x OK\n");
    if (typecheck(double, x))
        printf("double x OK\n");
    return(0);
}
```

Compilation message:

```
$ /usr/bin/gcc -O3 -g -std=gnu99 -Wall -Wextra xx.c -o xx  
xx.c: In function ‘main’:
xx.c:15: warning: comparison of distinct pointer types lacks a cast
$
```

Note that because I did not use `-Werror`, the code compiled 'OK'.  The output was:

```
int x OK
double x OK
```

Comment: char buffer_array[10];
char *buffer_point;  typecheck(typeof(&buffer_array), buffer_point) give the waring "comparison of distinct pointer types lacks a cast". what is the type of &buffer_array which is not char *?

Comment: Given `char buffer_array[10];`, the type of `&buffer_array` is 'pointer to array of 10 `char`', or `char (*)[10]`.  Arrays are not pointers; they're closely related, but they are not the same thing.